# Adding runrules to eclipse run button drop down list

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I'm working on a plugin where I created a custom toolbar with some buttons in it. I choose one of them to be run button like in eclipse. How would I add options to this drop-down list like on the picture?

[image: How I want the button to look like]

The code I used to add a custom toolbar looks like this:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <category
        id="com.example.customproject.commands.category.customgroup"
        name="CustomGroup">
  </category>
  <command
        categoryId="com.example.customproject.commands.category.customgroup"
        id="com.example.customproject.commands.Build"
        name="Build">
  </command>
</extension>

<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="com.example.customproject.handlers.BuildHandler"
        commandId="com.example.customproject.commands.Build">
  </handler>
</extension>

<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
     <menu
           id="com.example.customproject.menus.CustomMenu"
           label="Custom Tools"
           mnemonic="M">
        <command
              commandId="com.example.customproject.commands.Build"
              id="com.example.customproject.menus.buildCommand"
              mnemonic="S">
        </command>
    </menu>
  </menuContribution>
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
     <toolbar
           id="com.example.customproject.toolbars.CustomToolbar">
        <command
              commandId="com.example.customproject.commands.Build"
              icon="icons/build.gif"
              style="pulldown"
              id="com.example.customproject.toolbars.buildCommand"
              tooltip="Build">
        </command>
     </toolbar>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

So it's basically just like this green run button on the picture except it doesn't have any options when I click on the arrow beside it.

Comment: If you want to create a drop-down menu, see here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Dropdown_Command

Comment: I updated my code and the question as you suggested.

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I want to add options to this toolbar button dynamically, not like in this example by changing plugin.xml.